# What does the "Business Rule F1040A-348-04" error mean on my rejected Free File Fillable Form?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, free-file-fillable-forms

I received the following error message:

> Issue : Business Rule F1040A-348-04 - If Form 1040A, Line 3 checkbox "Married filing separately" is checked (element 'IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd' has the value 3) and Line 6a checkbox 'ExemptPrimaryInd' is checked and Line 23a 'TotalBoxesCheckedCnt' has the value 1 and Line 23b checkbox 'MustItemizeInd' is not checked and Line 24 'modifiedStandardDeductionInd' does not have a value, then Line 24 'TotalItemizedOrStandardDedAmt' must equal 7550.

I don't understand what I am asked to correct.

Comment: What value do you have in line 24?

Answer (score 4):

If you are married filing separately, you need to choose the same type of deduction (standard or itemized) as your spouse. Since you checked the box on line 23b, you indicated that your spouse chose the standard deduction, so you must use the standard deduction also.

The standard deduction for married filing separately this year is $6300, but because you checked one of the boxes for yourself in 23a, you get to add another $1250 to your standard deduction, for a total deduction of $7550. This number belongs in line 24.